# Is there a way to change frequency and duration of the BEL (beep) in the non-graphical bash console?

Tags: linux, bash, console

I've seen many posts regarding *disabling* the `BEL` beep, or swapping it for a screen flash, but no way to change the frequency or duration of the sound.

I would like the duration of the `BEL` to be by default a third or a quarter of what currently is.

Can it be preset at the Linux kernel or something?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Formal note: IMO the question *is* on-topic here. It may be better suited for U&L SE, but this is no reason to close it. Where scopes overlap, the OP may choose which site he or she wants to ask on. An on-topic question may be closed [if it is cross-posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310); I believe this question has not been cross-posted.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for having the necessary knowledge to answer the question here! Nice work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setterm --bfreq=… --blength=…
```

> `--bfreq[=number]`
> Sets the bell frequency in Hertz. Without an argument, it defaults to 0. Virtual consoles only.
>
> `--blength[=0-2000]`
> Sets the bell duration in milliseconds. Without an argument, it defaults to 0. Virtual consoles only.

<sup>(Source: [man 1 setterm](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/setterm.1.html).)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll set this in rc.local and reboot, to see if it applies system wide.

Comment: @tokafondo I cannot test it right now, but I doubt your can easily do this from `rc.local`. `setterm` prints to its stdout and if the stdout is a terminal then the terminal interprets the sequence accordingly. AFAIK `rc.local` is executed without connection to a terminal. `.bashrc` or similar file would be my first choice (and because non-silent startup scripts may break `scp` etc., I would rather `setterm … >/dev/tty 2>/dev/null`). If you save the output from `setterm` to a file where it works for you, then *maybe* `cat file >/dev/tty2` and such will work from `rc.local`. Totally not tested.

Comment: I tried with rc.local and it did nothing. I tried with .bashrc and it changes BEL as requested, but only in non-graphical consoles. The X terminal emulators doesn't support setterm commands.